# BinaryReader returns the correct string but misses the first three characters

Tags: c#

I've written this piece of code to read from a file. When it reads from the file it returns the correct string except it doesn't save the first three characters. The program is meant to work with save files from the game satisfactory.

```
   using System.Diagnostics;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
   using System.Text;

   namespace SatisfactorySaveParser
   {
        public class FSaveHeader
        {
            public int SaveHeaderVersion;
            public int SaveVersion;
            public int BuildVersion;
            public string MapName;
            public string MapOptions;
            public string SessionName;
            public int PlayedSeconds;
            public long SaveTimeStamp;
            public byte SessionVisibility;
            public int UnrealEngineVersion;
            public string ModMetadata;
            public int ModFlags;
            public string SaveIdentifier;

            public void Parse(FileStream stream, string filename)
            {
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                int Length = filename.Length;

                SaveHeaderVersion = reader.ReadInt32();
                SaveVersion = reader.ReadInt32();
                BuildVersion = reader.ReadInt32();
                MapName = reader.ReadString();
                MapOptions = reader.ReadString();
                SessionName = reader.ReadString();
                ModFlags = reader.ReadInt32();
                PlayedSeconds = reader.ReadInt32();
                SaveTimeStamp = reader.ReadInt32();
                SessionVisibility = reader.ReadByte();
                UnrealEngineVersion = reader.ReadInt32();
                ModMetadata = reader.ReadString();
                ModFlags = reader.ReadInt32();
                SaveIdentifier = reader.ReadString();
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried different methods from the binary reader class as well as different ways of reading from a file.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with a BOM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012167/how-can-i-detect-if-a-net-streamreader-found-a-utf8-bom-on-the-underlying-strea

Comment: Strings need to have their length encoded. Your file probably uses another encoding than the dynamic 1-5 byte prefix of BinaryReader. Post the data and please point out which strings are affected or all of them.

Comment: Byte order mark was also my first thought. You can strip it like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317700/strip-the-byte-order-mark-from-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: Was the file written using a `BinaryWriter`? If not then that's your issue. The documentation for `ReadString` says "The string is prefixed with the length, encoded as an integer seven bits at a time". In that case, you should probably just use a `FileStream`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the file wasnt written using it, thanks for the info, should've looked at the documentation more carefully thanks.

Comment: If you're reading a `string` from a file then you have to know how much data to read. the `BinaryWriter` encodes that into the data and the `BinaryReader` reads that length and then that much text data. If you're reading some other file format then you're going to have to know how long the `strings` are. Either they are a known constant length or the variable length must be written in the file some way.